# From where was differentiability formula derived?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[Formula:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py2re.png)
$$
\lim_{\mathbf h \to 0} \frac{\|\mathbf f(\mathbf x_0 + \mathbf  h) - \mathbf f(\mathbf  x_0) - \mathbf J (\mathbf h)\|_{\mathbf  R^n}}{\|\mathbf h\|_{\mathbf R^m}} = 0.
$$

I can't understand how we get the formula of differentiability for multivariable functions (f(xo+h)-f(xo)-a*h)/|h|=0.

Comment: You have a stray $-a*h$ in there which doesn't look like it belongs.  In any case... differentiability is just the same thing as "average change" except we consider the limit as the range over which we are considering the change approaches a point.

Comment: I suggest watching [this lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-006-calculus-revisited-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/part-i-sets-functions-and-limits/lecture-4-derivatives-and-limits/)

Comment: If $f$ maps into the reals, how about looking at it as an tangent plane approximation and then turning the idea into a formula, just as in the one variable case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (full) derivative of a multivariable function $f$ at $x_0$ is a linear map $a$ such that the affine map given by "shifting" $a$ by adding $f(x_0)$ is a good approximation to the function $f$ itself near $x_0$. This means that the difference between $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)+a(x-x_0)$ should be small for $x$ near $x_0$. How small? Well, if $x-x_0=h$, then for "nice" $f$ the difference  $f(x)-f(x_0)$ is already comparable to $|h|$. The extra subtraction of $ah$ may help us make the difference higher order in $|h|$ - that is  make $f(x)-(f(x_0)+ah))$ be $o(|h|)$, meaning $\lim_{|h|\to 0} \frac{f(x)-(f(x_0)+ah))}{|h|}=0$. If this is achievable by using some $a$, then we say that  $f$ is linearizable, or differentiable, at $x_0$  and the corresponding linear map $a$ is $f$'s derivative at $x_0$ (while the map $f(x_0)+a(x-x_0)$ is its linearization at $x_0$).

Geometrically, the map $x\to (x, f(x_0)+a(x-x_0))$ is in fact a parametrization of the tangent space of the graph of $f$ at the point $(x_0, f(x_0))$; the condition $\lim_{|h|\to 0} \frac{f(x)-(f(x_0)+ah))}{|h|}=0$ says that the tangent space approximates the graph to a better-than-linear order.

Comment: Thank you,so what the formula is saying is that if exist a function f(xo)+ah that approximates the functions f(x) then we can easily find the tangent hyperplane by knowing the value of a.Also that shows that the function is continuos and derivable with continuos derivative right?@Max

Comment: It does show that $f$ is continuous, since continuity is just $\lim_{|h}\to 0 f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)/h=0$, which you can deduce from the differentiability. It does NOT imply that the derivative is continuous - the map/matrix $a$ can vary in discontinuous way from point to point; it may also exist in one point and  and not others.

Comment: Thank you @Max.